# Mesosphere DC/OS community license

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

It is legal to use DC/OS community in commercial usage? I cannot decide (set focus for learning) what to use -- Mesos or DC/OS.
Also what pros and cons DC/OS community edition versus Mesos?

Comment: 1. Yes, but you lose the enterprise features and support. 2. Mesos is part of the Mesosphere stack that DC/OS uses. 3. That question does not really make sense given the answer to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a formal "Community Edition" these days, there's the standard open source version and an Enterprise version which is sold with a license.

The open source version is Apache-licensed and perfectly fine to be used commercially.